# Google Play Game Services

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-games

I have been porting one of my iOS games to Android, and the implementation of the Game Services is proving to be a soul destroying experience.

In the dev console, when I select game services on the left, and then 'linked apps', the screen throws up the terms and conditions, which I accept.

A few seconds later the T & C reappear, and again, and again. I added my App, and on the off chance that I can time the click right to select it, I keep getting the terms and conditions box also. Should I manage to click the 'Authorize Your App Now', the screen throws up a blank box.

The Google play help section says a blank box means I have not accepted the T & C, which I have. At least 10 times each visit.

Am I missing something?

Even setting up Cocos2d-x, JNI and Eclipse was less annoying than this.

Answer (score 1):

https://console.developers.google.com/

Go here and accept T&C; if it hasn't shown up, try clicking your project first. And then it won't be a blank window.